# the first package can not been sent with nonblock tcp socket

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I am writing a tool with TCP protocol. The tool simulate 1000 TCP clients.When the socket fd is added to about 500, The follow-up to create the socket can not send data，and the send function return EAGAIN. why?

All my TCP socket is nonblock.

for example:

my test logs:

```
12 2012-12-03 23:21:56:41005 tang_dts_serv_task.cpp:55 [3] [17294] dts zero channel acc.[confid:41075200][userid:860194970]
 13 2012-12-03 23:21:56:41509 send_task_mgr.cpp:49 [3] [17348] send task mgr.[cmdcode:4354][fd:1026]
 14 2012-12-03 23:21:56:41529 data_send_task.cpp:51 [2] [17348] dts send task.[cmdcode:4354][fd:1026][port:25789]
 15 2012-12-03 23:21:56:41543 os_sock.cpp:15 [0] [17348] send error.[fd:1026][errno:11]
```

the socket 1026 just have been created, but the first package can not been sent.

my everionment:

```
Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS
Linux VM-Ubuntu203001 2.6.24-24-server #1 SMP Fri Sep 18 17:24:10 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

the send part:

```
void DataSendTask::ProcessMsg(message *msg)
{
    tcm_message *tm;
    DtsContext *ctx;
    ClientEntity *cli;

    size_t transfer_bytes;
    char *d_buf;
    int buf_len;
    int retval;
    EventHandler *handler;
    Reactor *reactor;

    tm = (tcm_message*)msg->content;
    ctx = (DtsContext*)tm->ctx;

    handler = ctx->event_handler();
    reactor = handler->reactor();

    SendBuffer &s_buf = ctx->send_buf();
    SockStream &stream = ctx->sock_stream(); 
    cli = ctx->client_entity();

    int sock_state = ctx->GetSockState();
    if (sock_state != DtsContext::CS_CONNECTED){
        LOG_ERROR("data send task socket state exception! [fd:%d][sockstate:%d]" ,stream.sock_fd() , sock_state);
        delete tm;
        tm = NULL;

        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    addr_len = sizeof(localaddr);

    OsSock::GetSockName(stream.sock_fd() , (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr , &addr_len);
    int port = localaddr.sin_port;
    LOG_INFO("dts send task.[cmdcode:%d][fd:%d][port:%d]",msg->msg_code , stream.sock_fd() , port);

    //1. Wei need to see wheter the half_package have unsend bytes.
    buf_len = s_buf.GetHalfPackageLength();

    if (buf_len > 0){
        transfer_bytes = 0;
        d_buf = s_buf.GetHalfPackagePointer();
        retval = stream.Send(d_buf , buf_len , MSG_NOSIGNAL , &transfer_bytes); 
        if (retval <= 0){
            LOG_ERROR("dts half send error.[fd:%d][send_bytes:%d][transfered_bytes:%d]" ,stream.sock_fd(),buf_len,transfer_bytes);
            if (retval == OS_SOCK_EAGAIN){
                //register event handler
                reactor->RegisterHandler(handler , EventHandler::EM_WRITE);
            }else if (retval == OS_SOCK_PEER_CNN_CLOSED){
                //connect again?
                ClientMgr::Instance()->ClientOffline(cli);
            }else{
                //error,print log info,continue;
            }

            s_buf.SaveLeftData(d_buf-transfer_bytes , buf_len - transfer_bytes);
            delete tm;
            tm = NULL;

            return;
        }

        s_buf.SetHalfPackageLength(0);

        LOG_DEBUG("dts half send success.[bytes:%d][fd:%d]",retval , stream.sock_fd());
    }

    PriorityQueue<DtsRtpPackage> &squeue = ctx->send_queue();
    while(1){
        //1. Get message from priority queue.
        DtsRtpPackage *data = squeue.Dequeue();

        if (data == NULL)
            break;

        d_buf = (char *)data; 
        buf_len = data->m_size + 4;

        transfer_bytes = 0;
        retval = stream.Send(d_buf , buf_len , MSG_NOSIGNAL  , &transfer_bytes); 
        if (retval <= 0){
            LOG_ERROR("dts send error.[fd:%d][send_bytes:%d][transfered_bytes:%d]" ,stream.sock_fd(),buf_len,transfer_bytes);

            if (retval == OS_SOCK_EAGAIN){
                //register event handler
                reactor->RegisterHandler(handler , EventHandler::EM_WRITE);
            }else if (retval == OS_SOCK_PEER_CNN_CLOSED){
                //connect again?
                ClientMgr::Instance()->ClientOffline(cli);
            }else{
                //error,print log info,continue;
            }

            s_buf.SaveLeftData(d_buf-transfer_bytes , buf_len - transfer_bytes);
            tang_mfree(data);

            break;
        }
        LOG_DEBUG("dts send success.[bytes:%d][fd:%d]",retval , stream.sock_fd());

        tang_mfree(data);
    }

    delete tm;
    tm = NULL;

    LOG_DEBUG("dts send over.[fd:%d]", stream.sock_fd());
}
```

Comment: @sje397,the first package can not been sent after the socket is created. the new socket's send buffer can be full?

Comment: could there be some shared resource somewhere? in the tcp stack or something?

Comment: @sje397 I can't understand your ideas,can you give me some details?

Comment: Can you perhaps show some code?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hi , i have added the send function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use non-blocking sockets, you have to expect that some of the time you will attempt an operation at a time when it would have to block. That's just the nature of non-blocking sockets. They return an error when they would otherwise have blocked.

Your code is as follows:

```
    retval = stream.Send(d_buf , buf_len , MSG_NOSIGNAL , &transfer_bytes); 
    if (retval <= 0){
        LOG_ERROR("dts half send error.[fd:%d][send_bytes:%d][transfered_bytes:%d]" ,stream.sock_fd(),buf_len,transfer_bytes);
        if (retval == OS_SOCK_EAGAIN){ // <- HERE
            //register event handler
            reactor->RegisterHandler(handler , EventHandler::EM_WRITE);
        }else if (retval == OS_SOCK_PEER_CNN_CLOSED){
            //connect again?
            ClientMgr::Instance()->ClientOffline(cli);
        }else{
            //error,print log info,continue;
        }
```

So it already handles this case correctly, retrying the write when there's buffer space available. I would just change the code not to log `OS_SOCK_EAGAIN` or `OS_SOCK_PEER_CNN_CLOSED`, since these are not actually errors but normal, expected conditions.

Comment: the first package can not been sent after the socket is created. the new socket's send buffer can be full?

Comment: The socket's send buffer being full is only one reason the send operation might block. The system being low on buffer space overall is another. (Also, don't use the term "package". It sounds confusingly like "packet". This is just a bunch of bytes, all or part of a message.)

Comment: Yes,you are right.the first byte can't been sent. is it possible?

Comment: Definitely. Some operating systems do this a lot, but it's very rare on modern Linux systems. The problem might be something else or you just might have an unusual configuration where network resources are limited or limited to your process/user/vm. Are there are any other symptoms?